# Sorting/filtering QList in QAbstractListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qabstractlistmodel

I want to sort and filter `QList` with custom objects (by it's attributes), which is an attribute in `QAbstractListModel` derived class, but I can't figure out decomposition. I think I should use `QSortFilterProxyModel`, because it looks like it do exactly what I need, but I really can't tell.

I am currently projecting my model to QML (`GridView`).

Should I make new class derived by my model (class derived from `QAbstractListModel`), or should I make it other way? I can't figure out how does filtering by multiple values (concatenation of those filters) works and how can I implement it in `QSortFilterProxyModel`. I can figure out that after filtering I can simply sort them by attributes of objects in QList.

What's the best (or at least good) solution for filtering and sorting in model?

Comment: Yes use `QSortFilterProxyModel` I usually derive from it in my usage.

Comment: @drescherjm But should I make new class or somehow implement it in class derived from QAbstractListModel?

Comment: ***But should I make new class or somehow implement it in class derived from QAbstractListModel?*** No just pass your `QAbstractListModel` to your `QSortFilterProxyModel` object using `setSourceModel(listModelPointer)`.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, I'll try it, thank you

Comment: https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel I personally use this library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple QML based application which shows a basic list view with text item on which user can perform the filtering of items.

https://github.com/freakMeduza/Qt-QML-search-panel

For sorting you can add one more Q_INVOKABLE function into class FilterProxyModel:

```
void FilterProxyModel::setSortOrder(bool checked)
{
 if(checked)
 {
 this->sort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);
 }
 else
 {
 this->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
 }
}
```

after that add some controls to QML form for checking it.

Comment: as i saw asker used QML: "I am currently projecting my model to QML (GridView)."